# Font for numbers changed when used fontspec

Tags: luatex, fontspec, math-fonts

The following MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{newpxtext}
\usepackage{eulerpx}
\begin{document}           
$1234$
\end{document}
```

has the correct output when compiled with pdfLaTeX (TeX Live 2022, Overleaf; the numbers are provided by the `eulerpx` package):

[image]

However, when I compile the following modified version with LuaLaTeX (TeX Live 2022, Overleaf), the fonts of the numbers are changed (to `Computer Modern`, I guess):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsbook}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{eulerpx}
\usepackage{fontspec}

% fontspec counterpart to \usepackage{newpxtext}
\setmainfont{TeXGyrePagellaX}[
Extension      = .otf ,
UprightFont    = *-Regular ,
BoldFont       = *-Bold ,
ItalicFont     = *-Italic ,
BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic ,
]

\begin{document}           
$1234$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is there some way to fix this issue? perhaps by adding an extra setting into `\setmainfont`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why loading `eulerpx`. Anyway, here's a “somewhat working”. Expect problems with accents.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsbook}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{eulerpx}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  % fix eulerpx, but expect problems
  % Declare text font as operator font
  \DeclareSymbolFont{operators}{\encodingdefault}{\rmdefault}{m}{n}%
  \SetSymbolFont{operators}{bold}{\encodingdefault}{\rmdefault}{b}{n}%
  %\def\operator@font{\mathgroup\symoperators}
  % Declare text font as math alphabets
  \DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathrm}{operators}%
  \DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathsf}{\encodingdefault}{\sfdefault}{m}{n}%
  \DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathit}{\encodingdefault}{\rmdefault}{m}{it}%
  \DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathtt}{\encodingdefault}{\ttdefault}{m}{n}%
  \SetMathAlphabet{\mathsf}{bold}{\encodingdefault}{\sfdefault}{b}{n}%
  \SetMathAlphabet{\mathit}{bold}{\encodingdefault}{\rmdefault}{b}{it}%
  \SetMathAlphabet{\mathtt}{bold}{\encodingdefault}{\ttdefault}{b}{n}%
  \DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbf}{\encodingdefault}{\rmdefault}{b}{n}%
}

% fontspec counterpart to \usepackage{newpxtext}
\setmainfont{TeXGyrePagellaX}[
  Extension      = .otf ,
  UprightFont    = *-Regular ,
  BoldFont       = *-Bold ,
  ItalicFont     = *-Italic ,
  BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic ,
]

\begin{document}

$1234$

\end{document}
```

We need to delay the settings `eulerpx` does, and also remove all mentions of `OT1`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I use `eulerpx` because I prefer upright math fonts. Sadly, this package causes several problems.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the `TeXGyrePagellaX` fonts for text and `Euler` font for maths you could try the `euler-math` package with LuaLaTeX:

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
 \usepackage{mathtools}
 \usepackage{euler-math}
 \setmainfont{TeXGyrePagellaX}[
   Extension      = .otf ,
   UprightFont    = *-Regular ,
   BoldFont       = *-Bold ,
   ItalicFont     = *-Italic ,
   BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic ,
 ]
 \begin{document}
  $1234\quad (x+y)(x-y) = x^2 - y^2$
 \end{document}
```

[image]